# How to have an input with a submit image inside?

Tags: css, input

I have an text input box which needs to be used as a search.

```
<input type="text" id="search"/>

#search {border-radius:4em;height:1.6em; background:url(Img/search.png) no-repeat; }
```

I can give it a radius to make the corners curved. I can put an image next to it as the submit button for the search. But how do I make it look like...

[image]

I cant seem to work it out? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit on hitting `Enter`. If you put an input in a form, and have focus on said input, when you press enter the browser will by default submit the form.

But if you are still keen on javascript method, submit the search query by simply doimg `$("#searchForm").submit()`

Also for your magnifying glass try `position:relative` since I assume that the space it occupies is not used up transparently by the typed text

Answer (score 0):

Just plain guess - did you try attribute `background-image`?

Comment: but how do I do it so that if they click on the image it triggers jquery click?

Comment: Okay, thats completly another question ... :) Styling wise I would try the above. If you need Jqery click that would be worser... Will think about it if I have anything for you...

Comment: I always control my forms with jquery and completely ignore the default. Can you not use a container div with the background image, and when they click it collect the info from the fields again using jquery?